# Table using grid size from user in Python

Tags: python

A program to draw a table using grid size. The user is prompt to enter the size - I don't know why I have the syntax error

```
def getgridsize():
  aRowLength=int(input("Enter grid size, max 20:\n"))
  while aRowLength<=0 and aRowLength>20:
    aRowLength=int(input("Please enter the size of the gird, max 20: \n")
  
  GetGridRow(aRowLength)
  
def GetGridRow(aRowLength):
    # draws a single row using |_ for each square
  thisRow = '|_' * (aRowLength)
    # add closing | to row
  thisRow = thisRow + '|'
  return thisRow

def DisplayGrid(aGridSize, aRow):
  aGridSize=int(input("Enter the grid size:"))
    # display top of grid using _ as top of each square
  print(' _' * aGridSize)
    # display rows of |_| for each row
  for rowCount in range(aGridSize):
    print(aRow)

def main():
  getgridsize()
  DisplayGrid(aGridSize, rowToDraw)
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole stack-trace from when you get the error? Also a input / expected output would be great as well.

Comment: It's for sure this row though, that is making the syntax error: `aRowLength=int(input("Please enter the size of the gird, max 20: \n")`. It's missing a closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now! hope some finds this helpful :)

```
  def getgridsize():
  aRowLength=int(input("Enter grid size, max 20:\n"))
  while aRowLength<=0 and aRowLength>20:
    aRowLength=int(input("Please enter the size of the gird, max 20: \n"))
  if aRowLength>0 and aRowLength<=20:
    GetGridRow(aRowLength)
  
def GetGridRow(aRowLength):
    # draws a single row using |_ for each square
  thisRow = '|_' * (aRowLength)
    # add closing | to row
  thisRow = thisRow + '|'
  
  DisplayGrid(thisRow)

def DisplayGrid(thisRow):
  aGridSize=int(input("Enter the grid size:"))
    # display top of grid using _ as top of each square
  print(' _' * aGridSize)
    # display rows of |_| for each row
  for rowCount in range(aGridSize):
    print(thisRow)

def main():
  getgridsize()
```

Comment: There is something wrong in it though - If user enters 20*5 the first-row won't have the top grid after the first 5